# Is it possible to receive rpc-websocket json request in angular from python?

Tags: python, angular, websocket, electron, json-rpc

My client is based on angular and electron, the server is written in python language.
I am able to send json-rpc requests between python-python and angular-angular.
I want to send a json object to client using json-rpc websocket from python to angular.

I am a noob so not really sure if it is possible or if there's a library available as I cannot find anything cross platform. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, there seems only python 3.x rpc websocket support.
Look for 'jsonrpcclient[websockets]'. There is a server available too.

On angular side, I can only suggest 'rpc-websockets'